# I cant read parquet file by pandas read_parquet function

Tags: python, timestamp, parquet

when I use pd.read_parquet to read a parquet file this error is displayed

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet("fhv_tripdata_2018-05.parquet")
```

error:

```
ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[us] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 32094334800000000
```

I want to convert this file to csv:

> https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/fhv_tripdata_2018-05.parquet

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a minimal example, i.e., a small parquet file that generates the error.

It seems there are some open issues with this. Conventions are not compatible and apparently there are pitfalls in reading/writing dates in parquet via pandas. Thus, I propose a solution by directly using pyarrow:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
table = pq.read_table('fhv_tripdata_2018-05.parquet')
table.to_pandas(timestamp_as_object=True)
// to csv
table.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Note the extra flag `timestamp_as_object` which prevents the overflow you observed.

Comment: I want to convert this file to csv:https://d37ci6vzurychx.cloudfront.net/trip-data/fhv_tripdata_2018-05.parquet

Comment: From pandas a simple `table.to_csv('data.csv')` will do.

Comment: So, die this work?